# Why isn't this div centered vertically in the viewport?

Tags: css

I have a div (id='canvas') inside another div (id='wrap'). The following code centers the canvas horizontally, but the top of it is hugging the top of the page, instead of floating to the center as I would expect. What am I missing?

```
body {
  margin:0px;
  background:#333
}

#wrap{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vw;
  padding:auto;
}

#canvas{
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin:auto;
  background:#fff;
}
```

http://codepen.io/djminkus/pen/vKmkOE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `auto` in `margin:auto` applies only to horizontal alignment.

Try with:

```
#canvas{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background:#fff;
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  background: #333
}
#wrap {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vw;
}
#canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id='wrap'>
  <div id='canvas'></div>
</div>
```

Or with:

```
#canvas{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; left:50%;

  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;

  margin: -200px; /* half!!!! */

  background:#fff;
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  background: #333
}
#wrap {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vw;
}
#canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: -50px; /* half!!!! */
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id='wrap'>
  <div id='canvas'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It worked, thank you. Is that really the simplest way?

Comment: `left` and `top` are the most top-left coordinates, than you need to negative margin in order to reposition

Comment: @DJG the `margin` version is crossBrowser.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just center things vertically without `display:table` or `flexbox` (or the translate trick)

Try this

```
body,html {
  margin:0px;
  background:#333;
  height:100%;
}

#wrap{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
  padding:auto;
  display:table;
}

#canvas{
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  text-align:center;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin:auto;
  background:#fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think flex box can solve your issue here:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.item {
  max-width: 50%;
}

<div class="container">
<div class="item"></div>
</div>
```